# Vuex multiple passing arrays or some other way

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

There is a component filter with checkbox buttons. When you click on the button, the api gives 20 products in this category. And they are displayed on the page.

**Component**

```js
    this.$store.commit(
     'showFilteredList',
     response.data.items
    );
```

**filter.js**

```js
    state: {
     filteredBrands: []
    },

    mutations: {
     showFilteredList(state, payload) {
     if(payload.length < 1) {
      console.log('clear');
     } else {
      state.filteredBrands = payload;
      }
     }
    }
```

The problem is that if I select 1 more checkbox, then other products from the category arrive, the previous ones are overwritten by `state.filteredBrands = payload;`, associated with this line. But `state.filteredBrands.push(payload)` won't work. In general, I would like the products to be displayed on the page when two or more checkboxes are selected; if the checkbox is removed from any one, the products are removed.

What needs to be changed or added?

Comment: What do you mean by `pushing doesn't work`? Can you clarify this?

Comment: @Anatoly ```state.filteredBrands.push(payload)```

Comment: Hmm. You need `state.filteredBrands.push(...payload)` and clear this array if there are less than 2 categories selected

Comment: @Anatoly Wow, ```(...payload)``` works for me. thx <3 Since this is a checkbox, I would like to clear the corresponding category when I click it again, is this possible?

Comment: You need to pass categories and brands to `showFilteredList` together to decide either you need to add brands to an array or clear it

Comment: @Anatoly If i want only brands, how i can check if my items already in array?

Comment: You can compare both arrays using lodash or yourself and keep only unique elements